# Install SQL Server 2014 LocalDb for Azure testing?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, localdb, sql-server-2014

I have a web site running in an Azure Cloud Services Web Role, which uses an Azure SQL Database. For development, I use SQL Server LocalDb, which was installed with Visual Studio 2013.

Now that SQL Server 2014 is released, should I switch to its version of LocalDb? Does the new LocalDb provide a more realistic emulation of Azure than the LocalDb that ships with VS2013? If I should switch, what should I uninstall and what should I install? Any other configuration changes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft has released an update to [SQL Server Data Tools](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/data/hh297027) which includes an update to LocalDb. The built-in Visual Studio 2013 Product Updates now includes the SQL Server Data Tools update.